# How to configure test-reports on Jenkins CI working with grails?

Tags: grails, jenkins

I configured JenkinsCI to build and run test on a grails application. 
But I don't understand the junit test-reports configuration.
I try to put target/test-reports/*.xml but I receive an error that the files does not exists.
How to configure it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The path you provide needs to be relative to the **workspace root**, which will be something like:

```
grails-app-name/target/test-reports/*.xml
```

If you're checking it out into a module (an optional Jenkins field in the "Source Code Management" section), you'll need the module name first:

```
module-name/grails-app-name/target/test-reports/*.xml
```

*Tip:*

Underneath the *Test report XMLs* field you're entering the value in, there's a link to the workspace root. Click it, and navigate to your test-reports folder; the path at the top is what you need to enter.

Comment: I try it but I probably make a mistake. At this time I didn't use any SCM but only my file system. So, the configuration *Project Base Directory* is on d:/dev/myproject I set the workdir : D:\dev\home_dev\jenkins\faqapp\target and in Test reports xml I put **/target/test-reports/*.xml but I would like to define d:/dev/myproject/target as output folder and it is not working.
If I try myproject/target/test-reports/*.xml I receive an error indicating that the folder does not exists. But it existing.